# How to get the dependency of jobs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can we find the job dependency in SQL Server?

Theoretically basing on the success of first one job the other job begins.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do this with job steps, not individual jobs.  However, I guess if you really wanted these as separate jobs, you could this:

Create job A:

```
step 1 - do stuff  
step 2 - call job B using sp_start_job

under advanced for step 1:

  on success, go to step 2
  on failure, quit the job with failure, notify, what have you
```

Basically, the only way you call job B is if job A's 1st step succeeds.